# Pulling Instagram Images In To WordPress and Programatically Creating A Post

Tags: php, instagram, wordpress, instagram-api

What I'd like to do is pull Instagram images to my WordPress website and create a post.

I have my code working for creating a post programatically and to pull in Instagram images. My problem is that I want to set the WordPress content for each post to be my Instagram image URL. I created a function that contains a foreach loop that contains Instagram URL. Calling the function isn't working.

```
function callInstagram($url)
    {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
    }

    $tag = 'dog';
    $client_id = "my_client_id";
    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.$tag.'/media/recent?client_id='.$client_id;

    $inst_stream = callInstagram($url);
    $results = json_decode($inst_stream, true);

    //Now parse through the $results array to display your results... 
    function testingInsta($results) {
        foreach($results['data'] as $item){
            $image_link = $item['images']['low_resolution']['url'];
            //echo '<img src="'.$image_link.'" />';
        }
    }   

/*  INCLUDE WRAPPER  */
// https://github.com/HarriBellThomas/Wordpress_PostController
require_once(get_template_directory() . '/class.postcontroller.php');


/*  USAGE  */
$Poster = new PostController;
$Poster->set_title( "tesing 11" );
$Poster->add_category(array(1)); //Use category ID
$Poster->set_type( "post" );
$Poster->set_content("<img src='" . testingInsta($results). "'>");
$Poster->set_page_template( "single.php" );
$Poster->set_post_state( "draft" );


$Poster->create();
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have commented out the `echo` statement in the `testingInsta`. However, I would refactor the code slightly so that your function returns a string, rather than echo'ing per-iteration.

```
function testingInsta($results) {
    $html = '';
    foreach($results['data'] as $item){
        $image_link = $item['images']['low_resolution']['url'];
        $html .= '<img src="'.$image_link.'" />';
    }

    return $html;
}
```

You would then want to amend your `USAGE` block to omit the `<img>` markup and instead just set the post's content to whatever the function returns.

If you're just retrieving a single image, there is no need for the iteration at all. Instead, you can simply:

```
if ( count($results['data']) == 1 ){
    $item = array_pop($results['data']);
    return $item['images']['low_resolution']['url'];
}
```

Comment: Hi @john-hall thanks for writing a reply so quickly!

Im getting this error

    Notice: Undefined index: data in line 290
    Warning: array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in line 291


Where line 290 is;

`if ( count($results['data'] == 1 )) {`

and 291 is;
        `$item = array_pop($results['data']);`

Comment: I left out some closing parenthesis, code is updated. Check if `$results['data']` is an array, which I assumed it to be based on the code sample you provided.

Comment: I add the parenthesis. I used changed my usage block to use your if statement. `$results['data']` is an array of all the data from an Instagram post. So what I've done is create a new variable `$results_data       = $results['data'];` and set this as my functions arguments and it works!!!

Comment: But I think the only problem with this is that I dont know how often its going to check if there is a new post with the specified hashtag. When I reverted back to using the foreach loop there were then LOADS of image URLs as the content of the post. How would you go about making sure a new post is created every time an image is uploaded with the specified hastag? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @StuartNelson you would need to have some means of identifying images and then skip those that you have already posted. I'm not sure how the IG API works, but if you limit your API call to retrieve say, just the 100 most recent images, that isn't so bad to process. You could store all images that you've posted in a database table, and when you're ready to make a new post, just ensure that the name of the "image to be posted" isn't found anywhere in that database table. You would want to fetch all records in the database table, store them in an array, and use in_array or isset() for that check.